# Prove that $\frac{(\prod_{i=1}^{n} a_{i})(1-\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i})}{(\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i})(\prod_{i=1}^{n} 1-a_{i})} \le \frac{1}{n^{n+1}}$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

> Let $a_{1}$,$a_{2}$, ... , $a_{n}$ be positive reals such that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i} < 1$. Prove that $\frac{(\prod_{i=1}^{n} a_{i})(1-\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i})}{(\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i})(\prod_{i=1}^{n} 1-a_{i})} \le \frac{1}{n^{n+1}}$ .

**`My Attempt:`**

Let $a_{n+1}$ be the positive real number such that $a_{n+1} = 1 - \sum_{i=1}^n a_{i}$ . Then,
$$\frac{(\prod_{i=1}^{n} a_{i})(1-\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i})}{(\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i})(\prod_{i=1}^{n} 1-a_{i})} = \frac{\prod_{i=1}^{n+1} a_{i}}{\prod_{i=1}^{n+1} 1-a_{i}} = \prod_{i=1}^{n+1} \frac{a_{i}}{1-a_{i}}$$

The inequality becomes :

$\prod_{i=1}^{n+1} \frac{a_{i}}{1-a_{i}} \le \frac{1}{n^{n+1}}$

i.e., $\prod_{i=1}^{n+1} \frac{1-a_{i}}{a_{i}} \ge n^{n+1}$

i.e., $\prod_{i=1}^{n+1} 1-a_{i} \ge n^{n+1}a_{1}a_{2}...a_{n+1}$

Now by A.M.-G.M.,

$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} 1-a_{i}}{n+1} \ge (\prod_{i=1}^{n+1} 1-a_{i})^{\frac{1}{n+1}}$

$(\frac{n}{n+1})^{n+1} \ge \prod_{i=1}^{n+1} 1-a_{i}$ since $\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} a_{i} = 1$

*How to proceed from here ?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By your work, $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n+1}a_i=1$.

Thus, by AM-GM
$$\prod_{i=1}^{n+1}(1-a_i)=\prod_{i=1}^{n+1}\sum_{j=1,j\neq i}^{n+1}a_j\geq\prod_{i=1}^{n+1}\left(n\sqrt[n]{\prod_{j=1,j\neq i}^{n+1}a_j}\right)=n^{n+1}\prod_{i=1}^{n+1}a_i,$$ which is exactly, what you want.